# Check if NaN in Tensorflow

Tags: python, if-statement, tensorflow, nan

I would like to check a tensorflow variable and set it to zero if it is NaN.

How can I do this? The following trick seems not to work:

```
if tf.is_nan(v) is True:
    v = 0.0
```

Comment: Are you certain that is_nan() returns a boolean?

Comment: It returns a tensor of type boolean

Comment: What is the shape of `v`? is `v` a scalar?

Comment: It is the cost of optimization. So, yes it is a tensor containing a scalar number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `v` is a 0d tensor, you might use `tf.where` to test and update the value:

```
import numpy as np

v = tf.constant(np.nan)                  # initialize a variable as nan  ​
v = tf.where(tf.is_nan(v), 0., v)
​
with tf.Session() as sess:    
    print(sess.run(v))

# 0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Tensorflow 2.0**

you can you:

```
import tensorflow as tf

if tf.math.is_nan(v):
    print("v is NaN")
```

or with numpy

```
import numpy as np

if np.is_nan(v):
    print("v is NaN")
```

Comment: Very nice they've added this.  This is so much cleaner than the original, but I guess it still is nice to know how to use `tf.where` and `tf.is_nan` if you need to do this kind of check on a vector (or batch) instead of on just a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tf.is_nan in combination with tf.cond to change values if the tensorflow value is NAN.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like numpy (*in this case, tensorflow*) often have their own boolean implementations, comparing the memory addresses of a custom boolean type, and CPython's built in using `is` is going to result in erratic behaviour.

Either just check implicit boolean-ness -> `if tf.is_nan(v)` or do a equality comparison `if tf.is_nan(v) == True`.

Answer (score 0):

To make everything a tf operation, I used this to convert a single value to 0 if it's NaN:

```
value_not_nan = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.is_nan(value)), dtype=tf.float32)
tf.math.multiply_no_nan(value, value_not_nan)
```

Answer (score -4):

I hope this can help you.   [math.is_nan](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan)

```
import math
if math.isnan(float(v)):
    v = 0.0
```

Comment: Not a tensorflow operaton, unfortunately useless answer